# SQL: Select all from column A and add a value from column B if present

Tags: sql, join, firebird

I'm having quite an easy problem with SQL, I just can't word it properly (therefore I didn't find anything in google and my title probably is misleading)

The problem is: I have a big table containing transaction informations in the form (ID, EmployeeID, Date, Value) (and some more, but only those matter currently) and a list of all EmployeeIDs. What I want is a result table showing all employee IDs with their aggregated value of transactions in a given timespan.
The problem is: How do I get those employees into the result table that don't have an entry for the given time period?

e.g.

```
ID EMPLID DATE       VALUE
1  1      2013-01-01 1000
2  2      2013-02-02 2000
3  1      2013-01-03 3000
4  2      2013-04-01 2000
5  2      2013-03-01 2000
6  1      2013-02-01 4000

EMPLID NAME
1      bob
2      alice
```

And now I want the aggregated value of all transactions after 2013-03-01 like this

```
EMPLID VALUE
1      0          <- how to get this based on the employee table?
2      4000
```

The SQL Server in use is Firebird and I connect to it through JDBC (if that matters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.EmpID, a.Name,
        COALESCE(SUM(b.Value), 0) TotalValue
FROM    Employee a
        LEFT JOIN Transactions b
            ON  a.EmpID = b.EmpID AND
                b.Date >= '2013-03-01'
GROUP   BY a.EmpID, a.Name
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` will list all records from the *lefthand side* table whether it has a matching record or not on the *righthand side* table.